# Unable to decrypt from stdin: "public key decryption failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: macos, gnupg, decryption

If I execute `gpg foo.gpg` I'm given a dialog that looks like:

```
   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │ Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key:  │
   │ "Edward A. Falk <falk@efalk.org>"                              │
   │ 1024-bit ELG key, ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,                         │
   │                                                                │
   │                                                                │
   │ Passphrase: __________________________________________________ │
   │                                                                │
   │         <OK>                                    <Cancel>       │
   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

and everything works just fine.

If I do `cat foo.gpg | gpg`, I get

```
gpg: public key decryption failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I've tried `--passphrase-fd 0` and `--batch --pinentry-mode loopback` to no avail. I *have* gotten it to work by putting the passphrase on the command line, but I really want to avoid that if I can.

I suspect that this is somehow related to the pinentry agent, but I don't really understand how to control the agent. (I really don't know why gpg even needs one.)

I'm using gpg 2.2.26.

---

One small word of explanation: my stdin doesn't literally come from "cat foo.gpg"; it's actually closer to `aws s3 cp "s3://myawsbucket.tar.gz.gpg" -` where the named bucket is far larger than I want to store on my local machine just so I can decrypt it and extract just one file from it.

Comment: You want gpg to read the encrypted file from stdin and also get the passphrase from stdin. I may be lacking imagination, but I don't think this can work.

Comment: gpg *could* have opened /dev/tty as another file descriptor and interacted with that. At least I think it could.

Comment: Adding on: yes, I just tested it. A program can totally open /dev/tty on a different file descriptor and interact with the user that way while still acting as a filter for stdin->stdout

Comment: However, it seems that while gpg *could* do that, it doesn't. That's a shame; it would have been a useful feature. My alternative is to write the password to a file, have gpg grab the password from there, then delete the file. Leaving the question open for now, just in case someone comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do differently. It turns out that if gpg-agent is running and properly configured, everything will work. gpg-agent knows how to interact with the user to get the passphrase. See the gpg-agent man page for further information.